# Share / invite box behind flash element?

Tags: css, facebook-sharer

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QMmjq5pkGVw/TpV47U4k6zI/AAAAAAAAC8s/arPL7LgOCzE/s800/cc.png

have no idea hw to fix this! help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the wmode parameter on the for the embedded flash object to `transparent`:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: This is great advice, in general, for making Flash play nicely with other elements in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I've done this before with an HTML element, but not an iFrame. I'm not sure if it would be any different. You can also try: <param name="wmode" value="opaque">

Comment: it's link to swf, and I iframe it.. can't~~